# Nesting HTML/PHP statement inside another PHP statement

Tags: php, html, drupal, if-statement

I have an IF/ELSE statement and I would like to print out some images that I am getting from my Drupal site. I can't figure out how to print those IMG tags without getting errors.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
   $field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_visitor_image');
 if($field){

        <img src="<?php print image_style_url('lead_teaser', $node->field_visitor_image['und'][0]['uri']); ?>">

            }
        else        
        { 

   <img src="<?php print image_style_url('lead_teaser', $node->field_banner_image['und'][0]['uri']); ?>">

        }        
?>
```

Comment: Oh no, php tags within the strings strike again.

Comment: `print` ? real coders use `echo`

Comment: I just love the peanut gallery around here. I am learning. So sue me if I don't act like a "real coder".

Comment: What's the difference between what you're printing in the `if` and the `else`? They look the same to me.

Comment: sue me if levity is a sueable offence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `echo` and string concatenation:

```
if ($field) {
    echo '<img src="' . image_style_url('lead_teaser', $node->field_visitor_image['und'][0]['uri']) . '">';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. That worked wonderfully. I appreciate you help!

Answer (score 5):

You have to break out of PHP mode when you start outputting HTML.

```
if($field){
?>
    <img src="<?php print image_style_url('lead_teaser', $node->field_visitor_image['und'][0]['uri']); ?>">
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest

```
<?php > inside another  <?php >.
```

One option for you could be to concatenate using ".".